# Scilab: "inconsistent multiplication" error message

Tags: math, scilab

I want to plot a curve with parametrisation x=... , y=... and z=... (see below). I keep getting error messages, mostly 'inconsistent multiplication'. Here is my code:

```
t = linspace(0,4*%pi)
x = (4+sin(63*t))*cos(3*t)
y = (4+sin(63*t))*sin(3*t)
z = cos(3*t)
param3d(x,y,z)
```

Could someone explain why I'm getting this error message or how my code should be corrected? I also tried to define x, y and z as functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation of * operator](https://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/star.html):

> Element-wise multiplication is denoted `x.*y`. If `x` or `y` is scalar (1x1 matrix) `.*` is the same as `*`.

So, in your case the formulas should be written as `(4+sin(63*t)).*cos(3*t)` because you want to multiply two arrays element-wise. Without the dot, the asterisk means matrix multiplication, and that fails because of mismatching size.

Examples:

```
[1, 2] .* [3, 4] // returns [3, 8]
[1, 2] * [3, 4]  // error; one can't multiply a 1-by-2 matrix by another 1-by-2 matrix
```

One can also write `3.*t` but here . is redundant since there is only one way to multiply a vector by a scalar.